# Parsing xml data and showing in the view

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the xml file in the local drive and want to show in the view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Houses>  <House name="House Country1">  <member>  <Name>A</Name>  </member>  <member>  <Name>B</Name>  </member>  </House>  <House name="House Country2">  <member>  <Name>C</Name>  </member>  <member>  <Name>D</Name>  </member>  </House>  </Houses>
```

My target is to parse the data in the xml file  and put in a model

The model is

```
public class HouseModel
{
  public string HouseName {get;set;}
  public List<string> MemberNames {get;set;}

}
```

I am trying the following code:

```
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\HouseInfo.xml");
            var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("House")

                    select new 

                    {

                        Name = feed.Element("Member").Value



                    };
```

This is give the output as **A** and **C**.

Is there any way to parse this xml file and extract the data into the model HouseModel like HouseName "House Country1" should contain members A and B , similarly with "House Country2" as well?

Comment: wouldnt serializing (serialisation of xml)  the xml  as HouseModel Object do the job for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\HouseInfo.xml");
var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("House")                
            select new HouseModel
            {
               HouseName = feed.Attribute(name)
               MemberNames = feed.Elements("Member").Select(m=>m.Element("Name").Value).ToList()
            };
```